# Sharepoint (office 365) online: HTML Script error

Tags: html, iframe, sharepoint-online, scriptblock

While trying to open a HTML page, scripts get blocked.[image]

By default, the dynamic generated  is blocking the script to run. How to overcome this and allow the script to run. The purpose of creating the HTML page is to render in multiple CEWP.

Please help.

Comment: Have you checked to see if allow custom scripts is enabled? You can check this in the SharePoint admin centre in the settings menu.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, its checked. Even its checked, Itried via Sharepoint Online Management Shell and waited for 24 hours, No result. Later raised a ticket to MS support team. They have fixed the issue.